# Redirect url contains both numbers and letters with Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Im trying to Rewrite my url with this htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    ErrorDocument 404 mysite
    RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)$ /name.php?n=$1 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /age.php?e=$1 [NC]

</IfModule>
```

when i tried open link `mysite/abc` or `mysite/20`. Both of them are working but if try this `mysite/abc123` or `mysite.com/a2b2c`  the page show error message. `This page isn’t working`

How can i redirect those link `mysite/abc123` , `mysite/a2b2c` to my home page `mysite` with htaccess ?

Thank you!

Comment: `[a-z-]` - this character class matches only (lowercase) letters, and the hyphen. `[0-9]`- this character class matches only digits. So add a new rule below the two existing ones, with a character class that allows all of those characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try these rules:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/?$ name.php?n=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ age.php?e=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

`ErrorDocument 404 /` will forward all not found URLs to home page without changing the URL in browser. If you want to redirect those 404 URLs and want to change them to home (landing) page then use:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/
```